# Submitting Ajax request to node.js controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, node.js, jsonp

I am trying to pass the URL in my client JS to the controller in my Nodejs code. I can't figure out why its not grabbing the URL. I am able to submit the URL from my client side, but given the app, I need to pass the data and URL to the Node server to process through to the endpoint.

**Client side**:

```
var urlLocation = "http://www.url.com/rest/v1/cms/story/";
var saveImage = encodeURIComponent(dataUrl);
              $.ajax({
                  type: "PUT",
                  dataType: 'jsonp',
                  url: urlLocation + imageid.value + "/" + saveImage,
                  success: function (data) {
                    $(".share-link").html("<div class='alert alert-success'><p>Success! " + data.id +" was posted.</p></div>");
                      console.log(data);
                  },
                  error: function (data) {
                    $(".share-link").html("<div class='alert alert-danger'><p>Couldn't send photo: <b>"+ imageid.value + "</b></p></div>");
                  }
              });
            });
```

**NodeJS**:

```
var Controller =  function(){



return function(options){
    if(!options){
      return;
    }
    //console.log('protocol - '.blue, options.req.protocol);

    var base = require('./base'),
        request = require('request'),
        dataObj;

    console.log("postImage  Controller");
    base();

    options.callback = function(error, data){
      if(error){

        options.res.status("404");
        options.res.render('404', {
          layout: false
        });

      }else{

        dataObj = data;
      //  console.log("res DATA".red, JSON.parse(data).entity );
        options.res.send({
          id : JSON.parse(data).entity
        });
      }
    };

    return (function(){
      if(options.req.params.imageid){
        request.post(
            'http://www.url.com/rest/v1/cms/story/' + options.req.params.imageid,
            { form: { key: 'value' } },
            function (error, response, body) {

                if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
                    //console.log(body);
                    options.callback(undefined, body);
                }else{
                  options.callback(error);
                }
            }
        );
      }

    }());


  };

};

exports = module.exports = new Controller();
```

Comment: Usually, you would use the `data` option for `$.ajax()` to send data with your ajax request and it would then take care of packaging it as a query parameter for you rather than as a path like you are doing.

Comment: I changed `url` to `data`, so it looks like this:

`data: urlLocation + imageid.value + "/" + saveImage,`

and the PUT is now `http://localhost:3000/directory/?file=file_name.jpg&imageid=asdfasdf&callback=jQuery11010554125418420881_1428945652075` in the console. Why is it not using the url in the `urlLocation` variable?

Comment: When I try submitting again(even after page refresh), I'm only getting: `?callback=jQuery110106194634947460145_1428946302972` after the /directory/

Comment: The `callback=xxxx` s what happens when you use JSONP for cross origin requests.  That needs to be there for a jsonp request and your server needs to be ready to process it because a JSONP request is a request for a javascript  that will call the function indicated in the `callback=xxx` argument.  The `data` argument should be an object with key value pairs that will show up a `key=value` items in the URL.

Comment: I think you need to back up a few steps.  1) Are you doing a cross origin request?  2) Have you coded both client and server for the JSONP format?  3) What data exactly are you trying to send to the server?  4) What framework are you using on the server side?